# Using Spring Security with thread pools leads to a race condition when threads are reused

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-security, rx-java

I have a spring boot microservice written using RxJava. I have used spring security to secure it using JWT style tokens. Everything works fine until I added Thread pools using RxJava io schedulers. I have noticed a wired behavior when thread pools are used with spring security. When I save data, a userId is saved along with it. When I create first object after login as a userOne it is created properly. The same works for userTwo. Then say I logged in as userThree and create a new data, which is saved against userOne ID which is wrong ! The behavior comes only when I do things in a separate thread obtained from a pool.

My security config file is like so:

```
public SecurityConfig(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties) {
    super();
    this.applicationProperties = applicationProperties;
    SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable().and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated().antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll().antMatchers("/health/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new TokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                    new MyAuthenticationProvider(this.applicationProperties),
                    "/api/**", null, new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Unnecessary code was removed for the sake of simplicity and clarity. Not only with RxJava but also when `@Async` is used with spring created thread pools the same behavior exists. It's a kind of a race condition.

The cause could be this. The securty context get inherited to the child thread. Parent thread gets a thread from a pool and submit a task to that thread. The thread gets security context inherited. Once the task is completed, the thread is released back to the pool. Say when another request comes previously used thread is reused. I suspect the security context has not been erased, hence the data is saved under older user's ID.

This is just a mind map or imagination. Is that possible? If so what are the solutions to get around this issue. Is there a way to clear the security context before the thread is released back to the pool? How to acchieve the same with `@Async` and RxJava schedulers?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that when threads from a pool are re-used, any thread-local data will likely still be present in the thread. You are trying to use the security credentials by setting a global variable, and that is inherently insecure. J2EE programs can get away with that because the threading model is ... simplistic.

In an environment where a transaction can occur across multiple threads, you cannot use thread-local security credentials.

One approach that can work quite well with RxJava is to bind the credentials to a class context and execute your RxJava observer chains inside that context, closing over the credentials and ensuring locality of reference. You create an object for each user, bind the credentials to the user and then reference the user's credentials at each step where credentials are required.

Comment: Do you mind sharing any article related to this? Thanks !

Comment: You can certainly find articles on the evils of global state settings -- thread-local data is just a slightly more contained global state.